# jQuery/HTML - Horizontal scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, jquery-animate, horizontal-scrolling

I'm having trouble doing scrolling...What I want to do is after clicking a button making a div scroll left and another scroll right/ one goes out, second in. But I can't find any solution and I'am having trouble forcing the second div to go next to the first one and hiding it...Any ideas?

[Website](http://nitidus-consto.kilu.org)

Comment: We could really use some actual code from you. In the meantime, look at http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/

Comment: Just view source, it's not scrambled, I didn't wanted to put a 200line code in here... But basically I wan't a div to push another and vice-versa...

Comment: Your page links to six external javascript files and contains probably two dozen DIVs. Please simplify your code to the bare minimum containing the problem and post that here.

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear... The external files are not needed for this and the divs... Just search for page and inside it you have 2 divs, gallery and home I want gallery to be next to home but not seen and than after a click the gallery should push home to left.

Comment: See my Answer @David Debnar, you can apply the same technique and load all pages into one page with the use of DIVs and even hash-tags for bookmarking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read your question and this is what i have understood;

You are trying to animate a div with another div, and here is the solution:

View the fiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/HNY7R/

## HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="push" value="push me" />
```

## CSS

```
#container
{ width: 400px; height: 200px; position: relative; border:1px solid black; overflow: hidden; }

.main
{ width: 400px; height: 200px; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; background: green; }

.second
{ width: 400px; height: 200px; position: absolute; left: 400px; top: 0; background: red; }
```

## jQuery

```
$('#push').click(function(){

        var main = $('.main').css('left');
        var second = $('.second').css('left');

        if(main == '-400px'){
            $('.second').animate({ 'left' : '400px' }, 500);
            $('.main').animate({ 'left' : '0px' }, 500);
        } else {
            $('.second').animate({ 'left' : '0px' }, 500);
            $('.main').animate({ 'left' : '-400px' }, 500);
        }


    });
```

Comment: Ok..helped me a lot, but I have kind of a problem.. When I click show more content the height won't resize and I don't wan't a large site at the start, any ideas?

Comment: You should use `.outerHeight()` of the children to re-size the parent before animating